# JSF ui:repeat random order of elements

Tags: jsf, uirepeat

I have a code that is similar to the following

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.listOfA}" var="a">
    ...
    <ui:repeat value="#{a.listOfB}" var="b">
        ...
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

The problem is that the items are displayed randomly each time .. I would like them to be in the same order every time I load it.

any ideas?

Comment: What is the Java type of `bean.listOfA`? is it really a `List`?

Comment: The `<ui:repeat>` in the view is in the context of this question merely the presenter of the model. Your concrete problem is definitely not caused by `<ui:repeat>`, but by the way how you  prepared the model. Perhaps you used `HashSet` instead of `LinkedHashSet` to collect the values? This is a classic beginner's mistake as to collecting the values in a desired order.

Comment: ok thanks, u guys are right. I just forgot about that